# Flutter Sending signal. Lost connection to device. error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

When i change the screen with bottom navigation bar then my application crash and closing,
How can i fix this sitiuation.

when i add google map then i get this issiue.

Here my code first screen code;

```
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
            compassEnabled: true,
            scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
            zoomControlsEnabled: true,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
              _controller = controller;
            },
            initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,),
          SlidingUpPanel(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
            color: const Color.fromRGBO(235, 243, 249, 1),
            maxHeight: panelHightOpen,
            minHeight: panelHightClosed,
            panel: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: context.dynamicWidth(0.2),
                    height: context.dynamicWidth(0.010),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: AppColors.buttonColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Show all profiles',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: context.theme.textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(
                      color: AppColors.textColors, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 20,
            bottom: fabHeight,
            child: SpeedDial(
              
              animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.home_menu,
              children: [
                SpeedDialChild(
                  child: const Icon(Icons.abc),
                ),
                SpeedDialChild(
                  child: const Icon(Icons.abc),
                ),
                SpeedDialChild(
                  child: const Icon(Icons.abc),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

And here my second screen code;

```
return  Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(onPressed: (){
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/main');
    }, icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black,)),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Text('MESSAGE SCREEN'),
  ),
);
```

Note: This error not between the two screen. It's happen another bottom nav bar screen

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete code for a Page with GoogleMaps

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

class GMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const GMapPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GMapPage> createState() => _GMapPageState();
}

class _GMapPageState extends State<GMapPage> {
  late GoogleMapController _controller;

  final CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition = const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(50.075037772400385, 8.238458633147104),
    zoom: 15,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
            compassEnabled: true,
            scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
            zoomControlsEnabled: true,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              _controller = controller;
            },
            initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
          ),
          SlidingUpPanel(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
            color: const Color.fromRGBO(235, 243, 249, 1),
            maxHeight: 500,
            minHeight: 100,
            panel: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Show all profiles',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const Positioned(
            right: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            child: Text("SpeedDial"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```